# Sync providers under stock Android don't work on Droid Bionic (Motorola)

Tags: android, android-emulator, synchronization, motorola, motorola-droid

I'm trying to solve an issue I am having with the new Droid Bionic from Motorola. I've tried to install a bunch of simple sync providers such as https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync or the Official Facebook App from the Market.

Basically, I cannot add any accounts through the "Accounts" interface unless the apps providing those accounts were bundled with the device -- trying to add an account using the official Facebook app just doesn't do anything when you click the icon. Some other friends who own the Bionic see this too.

Does anyone happen to know if the android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS functionality is basically broken under Blur unless I do something Motorola specific in my implementation? I've searched around the Motorola website, and the developer forums are basically filled with people having issues with Motorola's customized software on their devices, but nothing specific to sync providers.

I have some apps that I'd like to make work on the Bionic, but they all use the "Accounts" interface. :(.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late to answer this question but I had the same problem and I found the solution. It is necessary to add the flag

```
android:exported="true"
```

in the AndroidManifest for the authenticator activity

Comment: I think you probably got the answer from my thread on the Motorola forums: http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Droid-Bionic-Can-t-add-a-sync-account-for-common-apps/td-p/18659